# phpmyadmin doens't open - it keeps loading indefinitely

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have XAMPP installed and it has been working fine except today. I can't open http://localhost/phpmyadmin/. The browser only stays loading the page. I get no error, it just doesn't open.

[image]

Comment: look for the mysql error logs, maybe you find there a hint

Comment: I was able to solve the problem following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=na4s3lwUAjA

Answer (score 1):

The solution you found was a Youtube link, but because Stack Overflow doesn't like external links and to save people with similar trouble from watching a three and a half minute long Youtube video, I'll summarize it here. The video shows changing the HTTP and HTTP ports for Apache (which involves editing the two configuration files with the "Config" button and the XAMPP configuration).

I can't think of why that would fix anything unless there was a corrupt cookie in the browser or if something were conflicting/blocking the usual HTTP/HTTPS traffic, and further troubleshooting could resolve those without needing to change ports. When troubleshooting problems like this, I often suggest trying to access the site using private mode on the browser and checking the webserver error logs.

Since you found a solution, you could post that as an answer (currently it's a comment; the large answer box is a bit further down the page) and then mark it as accepted.